# Having trouble getting JSON data from database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, database

So as the title suggests, I am having difficulty retrieving data from my database with these technologies. This is my current situation:

```
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

// For the sake of example this is a dummy IP
var url = 'http://55.55.55.55/dbfuncts.php?action=getuser&user=' + username;
// For debugging purposes I compare this object with the one I get with the ajax function
var obj1 = {
    "name" : "Dave"
};

var obj = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

The format of my JSON is supposed to be like this:

```
{"UserID":"User","Password":"User","Email":"User@questionmark.com","Fname":"Web","Lname":"User","isManager":"0"}
```

When I go to the URL I am able to see this JSON string in my browser.

Currently when debugging, I find that I keep getting the jqXHR object instead of the json object that I want.

How do I retrieve the information as a JSON from the database?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? It sounds like your request is being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), although this would depend on how the receiving domain is configured.

Comment: Are you running the JS from http://55.55.55.55 ?

Comment: I'm running JS from localhost

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jQuery ajax call will return the result directly as you did (but I'm not sure).

I used to get result from ajax call by using callback function as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // data argument is the result you want
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Place the url which gives the json data in the url column.

```
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
     url: '*',
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

If this does not then try this:

```
      var jsonData1 = $.ajax({
      xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
      type:'GET',
      url: '*',
      dataType:"json",
      crossDomain: true,
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  var parsed1 = JSON.parse(jsonData1);
```

TRY 2:

Ok so try it with Spring MVC. Get the data from the database, and keep it in a url. As given in this link. [Ckick Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) And then use the above ajax call to access the data from the url.